# Options to share a folder between Azure VM & local PC

Tags: azure, share

I have an Azure VM on line, do you know a way to share a folder between this VM and a local PC? for technical reasons we cannot use remote desktop to connect the user

Any ideas will be welcomed

Regards...

Comment: Use Azure File Service or set up a VNET with a VPN connection

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be creating a VPN Point-to-Site between Azure and your local computer and simply sharing a folder over the network.